# Is there a reliable way to determine if `requestPermissions` will actually display the prompt?

Tags: android, push-notification

I need to migrate our Android app to be compatible with Android 13. I was following [this doc](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission) to enable the permission to send push notifications. However we have a different workflow to request the permission than what is recommended in the doc. For example, we do not want to show the OS prompt upfront without displaying an educational UI, even at the first time we request the permission.

In the doc:

> If your app targets Android 13 or higher, your app has complete control over when the permission dialog is displayed.

Apparently this is not true. I created an empty project to verify the behaviour of [`requestPermissions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String%5B%5D,int)) and here is my findings:

- If permission is enabled, the prompt won't be displayed.
- If permission is not enabled, I have two chances to click the "Don't allow" button. After that, calling `requestPermissions` will return immediately.

What I'm currently trying is a hacky way around this, and very likely to break:

- When the user clicks either the "Allow" or "Don't allow" button, set a "has_shown" flag.
- When either "has_shown" flag is set or [`shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String)) returns true, we decide the OS prompt can be displayed and display the educational UI.

Checking which button the user clicks is hacky on its own. What I'm doing is verify if either of the following satisfies:

- `grantResults` passed into the callback indicates PERMISSION_GRANTED.
- `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` returns true.

The flag is stored in SharedPreferences, so all this is based on the premise that the user never clears the storage.

Is there a better way I can achieve this?

Comment: Keep in mind that device administrators can also add restrictions that auto-deny certain permissions, so the permission prompt will never, ever appear on those devices, even the very first time you ask (in those cases, `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` is, of course, false, since you'll never get that permission, there is no reason to ever show any rationale).